# Adjective for "Bear"

Tags: adjectives

Is there an adjective for "bear" in a similar sense as how "feline" and "canine" are adjectives for cat and dog?

Comment: Related post: [Is there any difference between an ursine and an ursid?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202018)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I hope I have enough low rep, as I posted it.

Comment: Usually such words are derived from the Latin word for the animal, and often that it the formal name of the zoological genus. You can't rely on this, but it is worth trying it: find the genus name (here, Ursa) and look in a dictionary for a word beginning "urs-".

Comment: For an extensive list: [What's an adjective for “pertaining to donkeys”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255950)

Comment: I thought it was just "bear". There is something like a "bear hug", and please don't tell me the word "bear" in there refers to the noun. That would be odd.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As @mari-lou-a said (in a now deleted comment), according to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ursine) it is "ursine"

Ursine:

> of or relating to a bear or bears.

An example usage of "ursine":

> we noted that a preponderance of the evidence supports an ursine origin for the giant panda (*Giant Pandas: Biology and Conservation*)

Another synonym might be "bearlike". [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bearlike) has one definition that says:

> Like that of a bear